# Convert nonlinear problem as LP with absolute value

Tags: optimization, absolute-value, nonlinear-optimization

The problem asks to reformulate the following:

\begin{align*}
\min |x_1-2|+|x_2-10| & \\  
\text{s.t.}\quad |x_1-x_2|+2x_2&\leq2  \\ 
        x_1+|x_2-4|&\leq6
\end{align*}
Here's what I've got so far:
\begin{align*}
\min t  &\\
\text{s.t.}\quad x_1+x_2-12 &\leq t  \\
     -x_1-x_2+12 &\leq t  \\
     x_1+x_2&\leq2  \\
     -x_1-x_2&\leq2  \\
     x_1+x_2&\leq10  
\end{align*}
is this completely wrong?

Comment: Yes, it is completely wrong (and I fail to see how you even ended up in the model you have). As it smells home-work, I won't give the answer, but a hint is that you need a new variable for every absolute value.

Comment: Now I see how you managed to arrive at this faulty model. You appear to believe that $|x| + |y|=|x+y|$ and $|x|+y =|x+y|$, which is incorrect.

Comment: Correction: You don't need 4 new variables (although that's is what would be used in a mechanical translation), 2 is enough.

Comment: Yeah I see the mistake now. So I made 4 new variables, eg t1 = |x1-2| and t1>=x1-2, t1>= -x1+2. I think I'm good to solve it now. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction!

Comment: how do you do with only 2 new variables?

Comment: The last constraint can for instance be written as $-(6-x_1) \leq x_2-4 \leq 6-x_1$

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT.-Deduce the answer from the figures below.

[image]